# Does Google Play Store show pt-BR localization to pt-PT users?

Tags: localization, google-play

As per the title, does the Store fallback on similar language codes (pt-* or fr-* or sp-*) if one is provided?

For example, I'm in Portugal (pt-PT) and the app has a pt-BR description, will I see it or will I see the English (or automatically translated one)?

I'm about to upload 100+ achievements, iap and store description and I would rather avoid having to do all the regional variants if I can avoid it. I can't find an answer in Google's doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it out manually in the browser by adding `hl=fr-CA` to the link for an app that doesn't have a `fr-CA` translation. It picked up the `fr-FR` localized version.

Also there is some documentation that [explain the fallback languages for Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html). One would guess it works the same way for their store.